# .htaccess redirect for images

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have an image uploader. I would like for the users to be able to access there files by going to

```
http://sub.domain.com/4ed7612d52d57
```

using .htaccess. the original file is

```
http://sub.domain.com/msc4ed7612d52d57.png
```

any help appreciated!

Comment: Just read the documentation or any of the myriad of other questions concerning .htaccess.

Comment: so your image should get 'msc' prepended and '.png' appended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ msc$1.png [L]
```

This will rewrite all requests that fall through this .htaccess file so that `msc` in prepended, and `.png` is appended. This may not be exactly what you want, but according to all the information in the question it is the best I can do...

Answer (score 1):

If your files are only .png , better to add prefix 'images/'
 
http://sub.domain.com/images/933asdad

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^images\/([a-z0-9].+)$ http://sub.domain.com/$1.png [L]
```